# How to sum a specific column after a specific criteria (Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql, metabase

I have this code

```
SELECT s.name AS School,
        count(distinct u.id) filter (where ut.app_name = 'A' or ut.app_name = 'G') AS A,
        count(distinct u.id) filter (where ut.app_name = 'B' or ut.app_name = 'J') AS B,
        count(distinct u.id) filter (where ut.app_name = 'C') AS C,
        count(distinct u.id) filter (where ut.app_name = 'D') AS D
FROM "public"."user_tokens" ut JOIN
     "public"."users" u
      ON ut.user_id = u.id JOIN
      "public"."user_roles" ur
      ON ut.user_id = ur.user_id JOIN
      "public"."roles" r
      ON ur.role_id = r.id JOIN
      "public"."schools" s
      ON ur.school_id = s.id
GROUP BY s.name
having count(distinct u.id) filter (where ut.app_name = 'A' or ut.app_name = 'G') > 0
    and count(distinct u.id) filter (where ut.app_name = 'B' or ut.app_name = 'J') > 0
    and count(distinct u.id) filter (where ut.app_name = 'C') > 0
```

The result of above code is

```
School      A       B       C       D
------------------------------------------
P           5       3       2       5
S           1       4       4       9
T           2       3       5       2
U           2       1       3       1
```

I want to sum the column A, so the expected result will be `10`. Any enlightenment how to do it? Thank you.

Comment: See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html for grouping sets.  Specifically, `rollup` is what you want.

Comment: What happens to the rest of the columns?

Comment: Do you want a single row as result or the existing result plus a new column?

Comment: I want a single result. Just tried a subquery like
`Select sum(A)
FROM
(....`

and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already found the solution, as you wrote in a comment, this is just to show how to use an alias instead of repeated calculations in HAVING:

```
select sum(A)
from
 (
    SELECT s.name AS School,
            count(distinct u.id) filter (where ut.app_name = 'A' or ut.app_name = 'G') AS A,
            count(distinct u.id) filter (where ut.app_name = 'B' or ut.app_name = 'J') AS B,
            count(distinct u.id) filter (where ut.app_name = 'C') AS C,
            count(distinct u.id) filter (where ut.app_name = 'D') AS D -- can be removed, not used
    FROM "public"."user_tokens" ut JOIN
         "public"."users" u
          ON ut.user_id = u.id JOIN
          "public"."user_roles" ur
          ON ut.user_id = ur.user_id JOIN
          "public"."roles" r
          ON ur.role_id = r.id JOIN
          "public"."schools" s
          ON ur.school_id = s.id
    GROUP BY s.name
 ) as dt
where A> 0
  and B > 0
  and C > 0
```

Comment: is this where clause only applicable on subquery? if it's not a subquery can i use this or use the having clause instead?

Comment: Aliases can be used only in ORDER BY (at least in Standard SQL) because the Select list is calculated *after* FROM/WHERE/GROUP BY/HAVING, thus you have to repeat the COUNTs in HAVING. But the aliases assigned in a subquery (Derived Table) or Common Table Expression/CTE can be used in the outer Select (there's a new set of WHERE/GROUP BY/HAVING), this is handy to avoid copying code like a huge CASE.